# CSS header div won't align to the left in IE, but works in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have the following asp.net page with a fixed header at the top with width 100%. The underlying content is centrally aligned and scrolls under the header.

This works perfectly when save as afile an opened in Firefox and Chrome, but will not work in IE9. In IE9 the header aligns everything to the left ?

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nsyns/)

Full page with css

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <style>

    #header {
        margin: 0;
        padding-top: 5px;
        height: 25px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: orange; /*#E1E1E0;*/
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1000;
    }

    .header_link {
        float: right;
        margin-top: 3px;
        margin-right: 15px;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #284E98 !important;
        font-size: small;
    }


    .content {
        width: 900px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        background-color: red; /* added to show problem */
    }   

    </style>



    <div id="header">
        <a href="./About.aspx" class="header_link" onclick="return hs.htmlExpand(this, { objectType: 'ajax' })">About</a>       
        <a href="./Default.aspx" class="header_link">Home</a>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <p>foo</p>
        <p>foo</p>
        <p>foo</p>
        <p>foo</p>
        <p>foo</p>
        <p>foo</p>
        <p>foo</p>
        <p>foo</p>
        <p>foo</p>
        <p>foo</p>
        <p>foo</p>
        <p>foo</p>
        <p>foo</p>
        <p>foo</p>
        <p>foo</p>  
    </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works perfect also in IE9.

Comment: Unless all our test boxes are wrong, it doesnt work in IE9. Did you save the file as HTML and open it in IE9?

Comment: save? we only look at the jsFiddle. works fine here too

Comment: Have you got a `<!DOCTYPE>` at the top of your page? If not, IE will go into quirks mode, which will give you all kinds of CSS problems.

Comment: @Ryan de Vries, by save i meant to copy the code in the question and save as a .html file, then open in IE9. sorry if that wasn't clear on my part

Comment: clearly this is the problem of <!DOCTYPE> as mentioned by Spudley in above comment. because this is working fine in jsfiddle. Please check it.

Comment: @Spudley, thankyou the <!DOCTYPE> fixed it. If you want to post as an answer I can accept

Comment: @SkeetJon - answer added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have a `<!DOCTYPE>` at the top of all HTML pages.

Without it, IE will drop into Quirks mode, which will cause all kinds of CSS errors.

Add a valid doctype to your page. If you're not sure which doctype to use, the best one would be the HTML5 doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Simple as that.

Hope that helps.